# is it possible to retrieve data from different databases from a single query?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, select

I am not really looking for a union like the questions that popped up that might be a duplicate of this question.

what I would want to do is query my database using data from another database. like,

```
SELECT * 
FROM ORACLE_DB.A_TABLE
WHERE SERIAL_NUMBER
IN (
    SELECT SERIAL_NUMBER
    FROM MYSQL_DB.A_TABLE
)
```

I am using SQL Developer as my IDE, and it seems that for every query sheet that I create, it is intended only for a single database.

is it as simple as this or do i need to add more values to the query like the credentials and stuff? or do i need to do some studying on a specific subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to access non-Oracle databases from within the Oracle DB, you need to configure [Heterogeneous Services](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58247/hs_ch6.htm). then you'd just create a database link and access the table like you would a normal table eg select * from table@mysql_db

Comment: sweet, thanks for the answer. I thought it is going to be easy as, I am just wondering if the DBA would be a little helpful on allowing me to setup heterogenous services. anyways, thanks again.

Comment: @simon if it helps i can print a full example of this but it was something i did for a friend that was using sybase. it should be similar for mysql though.

Comment: appreciate the offer, really. but just giving the thing that I need to study is already a lot of help for me. thanks :D